# could not access the kubernetes pod api from the new joined node

Tags: kubernetes

I have joined a new kubenretes node using this command:

```
kubeadm join 172.29.217.209:6443 --token jew814.e5iof6qwvzg46d9q --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:21919c93d652
```

this is the node status right now:

```
> kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME           STATUS   ROLES           AGE      VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8smasterone   Ready    control-plane   2y100d   v1.28.1   172.29.217.209   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)            3.10.0-1160.95.1.el7.x86_64   containerd://1.6.12
k8sslave01     Ready    <none>          22h      v1.28.3   172.29.161.175   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)   6.1.0-13-amd64                containerd://1.6.20
```

I am tried to make the kubernetes version of two nodes as the same as I can. the kube-proxy log on the k8sslave01 looks like:

```
I1112 09:12:24.749986       1 node.go:141] Successfully retrieved node IP: 172.29.161.175
I1112 09:12:24.750830       1 conntrack.go:52] "Setting nf_conntrack_max" nfConntrackMax=131072
I1112 09:12:24.770716       1 server.go:632] "kube-proxy running in dual-stack mode" primary ipFamily="IPv4"
I1112 09:12:24.777426       1 server_others.go:218] "Using ipvs Proxier"
I1112 09:12:24.777460       1 server_others.go:421] "Detect-local-mode set to ClusterCIDR, but no cluster CIDR for family" ipFamily="IPv6"
I1112 09:12:24.777466       1 server_others.go:438] "Defaulting to no-op detect-local"
I1112 09:12:24.777710       1 proxier.go:408] "IPVS scheduler not specified, use rr by default"
I1112 09:12:24.777899       1 proxier.go:408] "IPVS scheduler not specified, use rr by default"
I1112 09:12:24.777946       1 ipset.go:116] "Ipset name truncated" ipSetName="KUBE-6-LOAD-BALANCER-SOURCE-CIDR" truncatedName="KUBE-6-LOAD-BALANCER-SOURCE-CID"
I1112 09:12:24.777972       1 ipset.go:116] "Ipset name truncated" ipSetName="KUBE-6-NODE-PORT-LOCAL-SCTP-HASH" truncatedName="KUBE-6-NODE-PORT-LOCAL-SCTP-HAS"
I1112 09:12:24.778047       1 server.go:846] "Version info" version="v1.28.2"
I1112 09:12:24.778084       1 server.go:848] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
I1112 09:12:24.778478       1 config.go:97] "Starting endpoint slice config controller"
I1112 09:12:24.778572       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config
I1112 09:12:24.778639       1 config.go:188] "Starting service config controller"
I1112 09:12:24.778696       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
I1112 09:12:24.778789       1 config.go:315] "Starting node config controller"
I1112 09:12:24.778801       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for node config
I1112 09:12:24.879459       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for service config
I1112 09:12:24.879517       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config
I1112 09:12:24.879688       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for node config
```

but when I tried to access the kubernetes pod from k8sslave01:

```
root@k8sslave01:/var/lib# curl -k https://10.96.0.1:443
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.96.0.1 port 443 after 130551 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

also failed from pod on k8sslave01. what may cause this issue? is it possible to access pod on master only startup the kube-proxy?

Comment: After going through the title and description of the question, we can understand that you are facing some issues while trying to access kube-api from your newly added kubernetes node. According to the official documentation if you want to access the kube-api via curl or any other way, you should be having a service account and it’s token for authentication, follow this [official kubernetes tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/) for more information on methods for accessing kube-api

Comment: Hi `Dolphin` is your issue resolved..? if you are still facing some issues please revert back here. If your issue is resolved for the better visibility of the community I will post the same as an answer...

Comment: no, this document explain the token issue, that not the issue my facing. now the network is not accessable, not the token and cert, the token and cert just needed when I can successfully access the api server api. @KranthiveerDontineni

Comment: Have you created any service to expose your pod to reach outside the node. In general when we deploy a pod until and unless we do a port forwarding or service expose these pods won't be reachable from out side you can check this by either using telnet or trace route command, also check whether any firewall rule is blocking your TCP or UDP ports